# Does puppet master and agent must have same os version

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

Do Puppet master and agent system have same OS Version?

For example:
My Puppet Master version is ubuntu: 18
Whereas Puppet agent version is ubuntu: 16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having different OS versions is OK.

You just need to make sure your modules work on all client OS versions, which might require modifications depending on what you do in them.

Answer (score -2):

If puppet agent and master version different from each other it could be a problem. Some old puppet agents couldn't get manifests from newer version of puppet master. If agent gets manifest from master maybe some deprecation errors can occur. You need to test first.

Comment: The question was asking about different OS versions, not versions of Puppet.

Comment: Differen os version comes different puppet versions.